# How should the changeTrust Operation be used?

Tags: javascript-sdk, operations, stellar-sdk, horizon, trustline

If I want to create a trustline between my issuing account and new users accounts, how do I do this. I tried with this code:

```
const StellarSdk = require('stellar-sdk');
StellarSdk.Network.useTestNetwork(); // StellarSdk.Network.usePublicNetwork();
const server = new StellarSdk.Server('https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org'); // const server = new StellarSdk.Server('https://horizon.stellar.org');

// an arbitary list of trusted assets
const ASSETS = {
    'TestToken': new StellarSdk.Asset('TestToken', 'G... *issuer account*'), //name, ISSUER ACC
    'USDT': new StellarSdk.Asset('USDT', 'GCQTGZQQ5G4PTM2GL7CDIFKUBIPEC52BROAQIAPW53XBRJVN6ZJVTG6V'),
    'MOBI' : new StellarSdk.Asset('MOBI', 'GA6HCMBLTZS5VYYBCATRBRZ3BZJMAFUDKYYF6AH6MVCMGWMRDNSWJPIH'),
    'XLM': StellarSdk.Asset.native()
}

// helper function to get desired asset object
const getAsset = (asset) => {
    if (ASSETS[asset]) return ASSETS[asset]
    return StellarSdk.Asset.native()
}

//create the distributor account keypair
const distributorKeypair = StellarSdk.Keypair.fromSecret('S... *Distrubutor Account Secret*') //DISTRIBUTOR ACCOUNT
//create the new account keypairs to use
var newAccountKeypair = StellarSdk.Keypair.random();
var newAccount = newAccountKeypair.publicKey(); // newAccount account address, taken from random keypair's public key
var newAccountSecret = newAccountKeypair.secret();


//load the new account to create trustline
server.loadAccount(newAccountKeypair.publicKey())
.then(account => {

    // new transaction builder (convenience constructor grabs tx sequence number from account object)
    let builder = new StellarSdk.TransactionBuilder(account);

    //OPERATION 2: Change Trustline to trust the asset to be used on the platform.
    builder.addOperation(
        StellarSdk.Operation.changeTrust({
            asset: asset: getAsset('TestToken'), //asset
            source: "G... *issuer account*" //issuer account
        })
    )

    // create the transaction XDR
    let transaction = builder.build();

    // sign the XDR
    transaction.sign(newAccountKeypair);

    // submit to the network. this returns a promise (resolves or rejects depending on the outcome of the transaction)
    server.submitTransaction(transaction);
})
```

but got errors:

```
(node:17428) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Request failed with status code 400
warning.js:18
    at createError (d:Stellar\node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (d:\Stellar\node_modules\axios\lib\core\settle.js:18:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (d:\Stellar\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\http.js:201:11)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
(node:17428) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 3)
warning.js:18
(node:17428) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Can Anyone help me figure out what I am doing wrong. I got pretty much the same method of action to work for creating and funding the new account but this gives errors that I don't understand.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You have `asset: asset:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`server.loadAccount(newAccountKeypair.publicKey())` can't find your account on the ledger, because it's not *on* the ledger.

You need to create the account using `createAccount` before you can run any other operation on it.

Answer (score 0):

In your previous question you posted the link to the SDK API documentation, pointing exactly at the [`Operation.changeTrust`](https://stellar.github.io/js-stellar-sdk/Operation.html#.changeTrust) static method. So just follow the described method signature. It says that method accepts single argument - object with the following fields: `asset` of type `Asset`, optional `limit` as `string`, and optional `source` as `string`. So you should do the following:

```
const builder = new StellarSdk.TransactionBuilder(account);

builder.addOperation(
    StellarSdk.Operation.changeTrust({
        asset: new StellarSdk.Asset("TestToken", "G...*issuer account*")
    })
)

const transaction = builder.build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you use `issuer` as `source` in the `changeTrust` operation. This is incorrect. The `source` here is the account that trusts the `issuer`, whereas the `issuer` is in the `asset` the `source` trusts.